# Connection between rank and positive definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, positive-definite

I would like to know, is there a connection between the rank of a matrix and whether it is positive definite? Specifically, if I can prove that a matrix is not full rank, then can I say that it is not positive definite? If so, why?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If your matrix is a square matrix and has not full rank, then zero is an eigenvalue, therefore it cannot be positive definite.

Comment: If a square matrix $M$ is not full rank then it has a nontrivial kernel, meaning that there exists a nonzero vector $v$ such that $Mv=0$. In particular $v^{\intercal}Mv=0$, so $M$ is not positive definite.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Another fact that wasn't pointed out is that:
since the determinant is a product of the eigenvalues, and both PD and ND matrices have either all strictly-positive or all strictly-negative eigenvalues, you can deduce the determinant is non-zero, which makes the matrix invertible (i.e. the matrix has full rank).

Comment: @Leucippus It *definitely* answers the question: *"Specifically, if I can prove that a matrix is not full rank, then can I say that it is not positive definite? If so, why?"*.

Comment: Jack, your answer is correct, but claiming that this wasn't pointed out is rather daring: the two comments above state the same, and have been here for $4$ years.